# Complete URL in HTTPS connections

Tags: url, ssl, https, charles-proxy

I would like to know some connections that depart from my application.

So I use a proxy (in particular I'm using Charles for OSX) This works fine.

I have noticed that some of these connections are HTTPS (TLS). This is ok, but for these connections, I can only see the base URL and not the complete URL that is invoked. For example I can read: https://www.thewesite.com:443

I would expect not to see the body of the request but at least the header, and then also the whole URL I would expect to see it.

is that correct? is there a way to display the complete URL?

Answer (score 1):

Since URL and the rest of the HTTP header are inside the encrypted connection you would need to enable SSL Proxying (that is Man-In-The-Middle attack) for the specific hosts. See http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/